How does Pandas.Series.nbytes work for strings? Results don't seem to match expectations
The help doc for pandas.Series.nbytes shows the following example:
s = pd.Series(['Ant', 'Bear', 'Cow'])
s  

0     Ant
1    Bear
2     Cow
dtype: object
s.nbytes

24
<< end example >>
How is that 24 bytes?
I tried looking at three different encodings, none of which seems to yield that total.
print(s.str.encode('utf-8').str.len().sum())
print(s.str.encode('utf-16').str.len().sum())
print(s.str.encode('ascii').str.len().sum())

10
26
10

Pandas nbytes does not refer to the bytes required to store the string data encoded in specific formats like UTF-8, UTF-16, or ASCII. It refers to the total number of bytes consumed by the underlying array of the Series data in memory.
Pandas stores a NumPy array of pointers to these Python objects when using the object dtype.
On a 64-bit system, each pointer/reference takes 8 bytes.
3 × 8 bytes =24 bytes.
Link: nbyte source code
Link: ndarray documentation

The help doc says "Return the number of bytes in the underlying data."  Is this misleading?  Or is there some pre-existing definition of "underlying data" from which the correct understanding can be derived?

@MCornejo Personally, I think it is just misleading. However, if you are aware that Pandas is built on top of NumPy and if you are familiar with NumPy's use of memory for arrays then you can infer. Here is a link for deeper understanding: ndarray documentation
